# Given 2 arrays, returns elements that are not included in both arrays

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I had an interview, and did one of the questions described below:

Given two arrays, please calculate the result: get the union and then remove the intersection from the union. e.g.

```
int a[] = {1, 3, 4, 5, 7};
int b[] = {5, 3, 8, 10}; // didn't mention if has the same value.

result = {1,4,7,8,10}
```

This is my idea:

1. Sort `a`, `b`.
2. Check each item of `b` using 'dichotomy search' in `a`. If not found, pass. Otherwise, remove this item from both `a`, `b`
3. result = elements left in `a` + elements left in `b`

I know it is a lousy algorithm, but nonetheless it's better than nothing. Is there a better approach than this one?

Comment: "dichotomy search" - you mean binary search?

Comment: Look for `std::set_difference` implementation, its C++, but you can get the idea

Comment: Assuming array a has n elements and b has m elements...

Sounds fine by me, sorting gives you O(nlogn) + searching for each element is O(nlogn) + generating result array is O(n+m) for a total of O(nlogn) complexity (or O(mlogm) depending whether n<m)

Comment: @P0W [`std::set_symmetric_difference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_symmetric_difference) is probably better.

Comment: After doing the sorting, think modified merging as in mergesort.

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches to this problem. one approach is:

```
1. construct hash-map using distinct array elements of array a with elements as keys and 1 is a value.
2. for every element,e in array b
   if e in hash-map
      set value of that key to 0
   else
     add e to result array.
3.add all keys from hash-map whose values 1 to result array.
```

Answer (score 0):

another approach may be:

- join both lists
- sort the joined list
- walk through the joined list and completely remove any elements that occurs multiple times

this have one drawback:  it does not work if input lists already have doublets. But since we are talking about sets and set theory i would also expect the inputs to be sets in the mathematical sense.

Answer (score 0):

Another (in my opinion the best) approach:

you do not need a search through your both lists. you can just sequentially iterate through them:

- sort a and b
- declare an empty result set
- take iterators to both lists and repeat the following steps:

  - if the iterators values are unequal: 
    add the smaller number to the result set and increment the belonging iterator
  - if the iterators values are equal:
     increment both iterators without adding something to the result set
  - if one iterator reaches end:
     add all remaining elements of the other set to the result